# Factorization of $L^{p}$ spaces

Tags: lp-spaces

Is the following theorem true and if so does it have a name?

Theorem: Let $p$, $q$, $r\in\left(0, \infty\right]$ with $\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{r}$. Every $L^{q}$-function is the product of a $L^p$-function and a $L^{r}$-function.

I believe the statement is correct but I can't find the corresponding literature I need.

Comment: It's true, $\lvert f\rvert = \lvert f\rvert^{q/p}\cdot \lvert f\rvert^{q/r}$. I don't think it has a name.

Answer (score 1):

Correctness of the statement follows from 
$$
\lvert f\rvert = \lvert f\rvert^{q/p}\cdot \lvert f\rvert^{q/r}.
$$
Like Daniel Fischer, I do not know whether it has a name.

Comment: Is the result in more variables still true just because of this? For example, can we say that $L^q(\mathbb{T}^2)= L^p(\mathbb{T}^2)\cdot  L^r(\mathbb{T}^2)$

Comment: I think that it would hold, since we only need Hölder's inequality.